# How to create ConversionServiceAdapter - MapStruct Spring Extension

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am trying to use the build 0.0.1 of the MapStruct Spring Extensions. I am not able to get how the ConversionServiceAdapter class will be created? On the [official website](https://mapstruct.org/news/2020-12-03-mapstruct-spring-extensions-0-0-1-released/) it is mentioned

```
annotations and extensions defined in this project will generate a class acting as bridge between MapStruct’s conventions and Spring’s ConversionService API
```

What is the class they are talking about? Is it the ConversionServiceAdapter?
Following are my classes

```
@Getter
@Setter
@FieldNameConstants
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Car {

  private String name;
  private String model;
  private LocalDate year;

  Company company;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@FieldNameConstants
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Company {

  private String companyName;

  private Address address;
}
```

Assume that the CarDto and CompanyDto structure is the same.

```
@Mapper(config = MapperSpringConfig.class)
public interface CarMapper extends Converter<Car, CarDto> {

  CarDto convert(Car car); 
}
```

```
@MapperConfig(componentModel = "spring", uses = ConversionServiceAdapter.class)
public interface MapperSpringConfig {

}
```

Now should I be creating a ConversionServiceAdapter class myself like this or it has to be generated somehow by the Mapstruct spring extensions. If it is to be created by the extension, should I put `uses = ConversionServiceAdapter.class` in the `@MapperConfig` above? How does it work?

```
@Component
public class ConversionServiceAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private ConversionService conversionService;

  public CarDto mapCarToCarDto(final Car source) {
    return conversionService.convert(source, CarDto.class);
  }

  public CompanyDto mapCompanyToCompanyDto(final Company source) {
    return conversionService.convert(source, CompanyDto.class);
  }
}
```

I could not find any documentation or release notes on the website. There is a link to the examples on the [github](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-spring-extensions/tree/master/examples) but they are not enough and do not explain clearly how to use it.

Please ask for any details that you need from my side.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Thank you for using this little side project. :-)

Regarding your question: Yes, this is exactly what the Spring extensions project does at the moment: It generates the adapter class. So in your `MapperSpringConfig`'s `uses` attribute, you can point at the generated class. (BTW, you don't have to create a separate Config class, you may just as well rely on the individual Mapper's `uses`. This was only for illustrational purpose.)

Without any special configuration for the extensions project itself, the adapter class will be generated with this name: `org.mapstruct.extensions.spring.converter.ConversionServiceAdapter`.

If you wish to change this, add a `@SpringMapperConfig` annotation - see [this example](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-spring-extensions/blob/master/examples/packagename-and-classname/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/extensions/spring/example/packageandclass/MapperSpringConfig.java).

And now, as the project's maintainer, please let me apologize for the unclear usage. I'm still on the documentation, but this is actually the main reason why I've assigned a version number of `0.0.1`. The extensions works as it's supposed to. If you encounter any issues, please feel free to contact us on one of the usual channels.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply; the thing is the AdapterClass is not generated

Comment: You need the MapStruct processor itself _and_ the extensions project as annotation processor dependency. How to achieve that depends on your particular configuration (Maven/Gradle); but in essence, wherever you currently add the processor, you must add the extensions in the same fashion.

Comment: do we also need to add the annotation processor to the maven-compiler-plugin section? I have tried with and without that as well. Added the @SpringMapperConfig to the MapperSpringConfig and specified the package and className but even then the adapter class is not created.

Comment: I too had issues with getting it working based on the documentation.  In the end, I was missing an @ComponentScan("org.mapstruct.extensions.spring").  Perhaps a complete and concrete and discrete example in Maven would help as well because the examples are all Gradle and use relative project annotationProcesser directives which aren't very similar to how a 3rd party Maven user would handle things.

Comment: We've added some documentation to the latest master. Please feel free to add things you think are missing and open a PR.

Comment: Sorry, but you description is not clear at all, still having the same problem using version 1.1.1,  with maven,  the example you point to refers a MyAdapter class that is not present in the project so not sure how it can be referred.

Using gradle to build the sample makes this class appear magically which does not happen with maven, any extra help ?

Comment: The Adapter class is generated during the build process. If it doesn't happen with Maven, please compare the project setup instructions: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/spring-extensions/reference/html/#_apache_maven. Most likely you're missing a section in the compiler plugin configuration.

Comment: Hey Ray, thanks that was the problem I forgot to change the plugin configuration and add the spring-extensions, now I have a strange problem, although I used a MapConfig specifying my own package/className for the adapter, it did generate de Adapter as specified, but after some changes instead of using the configured class it generated the default adapter className in the default package,  I'll dig a bit more and probably if still not solved I add a question here or a bug in the project,  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in the following link, as of March 2021:
[Spring Extension Unit Test with Mapstruct](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-spring-extensions/blob/main/examples/packagename-and-classname/src/test/java/org/mapstruct/extensions/spring/example/ConversionServiceAdapterIntegrationTest.java)

Summary:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = {ConversionServiceAdapterIntegrationTest.AdditionalBeanConfiguration.class})
public class ConversionServiceAdapterIntegrationTest {
....
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.mapstruct.extensions.spring", "io.net.mapper"})
@TestComponent
  static class AdditionalBeanConfiguration {
    @Bean
    ConfigurableConversionService getConversionService() {
      return new DefaultConversionService();
    }

  }
    }
```